# zsh mystery variable expansion

Tags: zsh

I found this in `prezto` source code:

```
# Set the command name, or in the case of sudo or ssh, the next command.
local cmd="${${2[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|ssh|-*)]}:t}"
```

I've been reading [zsh doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) a lot but getting nowhere close to what this is about. In experimentation on the shell itself it seems to indicate the `[]` is some arithmetic thing, which makes sense, but I don't see the part that explains how `(w)` is supposed to work. It seems to be some magical operator that applies to the math expression...

```
slu@ubuntu-sluvm ~/.zprezto ❯❯❯ VAR="one two three four"
slu@ubuntu-sluvm ~/.zprezto ❯❯❯ echo ${VAR[2]}
n
slu@ubuntu-sluvm ~/.zprezto ❯❯❯ echo ${VAR[(w)2]}
two
slu@ubuntu-sluvm ~/.zprezto ❯❯❯ echo ${VAR[(w)]}
zsh: bad math expression: empty string
slu@ubuntu-sluvm ~/.zprezto ❯❯❯
```

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks pretty messy at first glance, but once you break it into its parts it's quite simple. This is an example of parameter expansion and extended globbing support in ZSH. If you look [higher up in the function](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/013668f484d1543cdadafac659a21e940df99957/modules/terminal/init.zsh#L40-L41) from which this code sample is, you'll see they set:

```bash
emulate -L zsh
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
```

So now let's break apart the line you have there:

```bash
${
  ${
    2[ # Expand the 2nd argument
      (wr) # Match a word
      ^(*=*|=|sudo|ssh|-*) # Do not match *=*, =, sudo, ssh, or -*
    ]
  }
:t} # If it is a path, return only the filename
```

You can  test this by creating a sample script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

emulate -L zsh
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB

echo "${$1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|ssh|-*)]}:t}" # changed 2 to 1, otherwise identical
```

Here's what it outputs:

```bash
$ ./test.sh '/bin/zsh'
zsh

$ ./test.sh 'sudo test'
test

$ ./test.sh 'sudo --flag test'
test

$ ./test.sh 'ssh -o=value test'
test

$ ./test.sh 'test'
test
```

For more information, see [the documentation on expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) and [csh-style modifiers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Shell_Scripting/Modifiers).

Comment: I guess the main disconnect is the difficulty in pulling up section 15 from e.g. google results